# getting error while installing black and safety

Tags: python

I am using poetry for python application. While adding developement dependencies as below

```
poetry add black flake8 flake8-import-order flake8-docstrings flake8-black flake8-bugbear safety mypy pytest-cov pytest --group dev
```

Getting error for `black` and `safety` as below

```
Because no versions of safety match >2.3.5,<3.0.0
 and safety (2.3.5) depends on packaging (>=21.0,<22.0), safety (>=2.3.5,<3.0.0) requires packaging (>=21.0,<22.0).
And because black (23.3.0) depends on packaging (>=22.0)
 and no versions of black match >23.3.0,<24.0.0, safety (>=2.3.5,<3.0.0) is incompatible with black (>=23.3.0,<24.0.0).
So, because project_titanic depends on both black (^23.3.0) and safety (^2.3.5), version solving failed.
```

Please help.

Comment: It's exactly as it says: you asked to use **exactly** `safety` version 2.3.5 (because there aren't any later versions than that and **exactly** `black` version 23.3.0 (because there aren't any later versions than that), and there isn't any version of `packaging` that they can agree on.

Answer (score 0):

Check your pyproject.toml file.
I had the issue, that the dependencies were added with the old poetry syntax:
`poetry add --dev safety`
instead of
`poetry add --group dev safety`
Just remove them from the file and install them again, so that they`re only listed under `[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]`

Answer (score -1):

Resolved after upgrading the poetry version.